# Date parameter to determine SELECT date range in shell script

Tags: bash, sh, sqlplus

I am trying to write a shell script that will use a SELECT query and spool the records into a csv report file. This script will be scheduled through the cron and depending on the date, will generate a report daily, weekly and semiannually.

We are using Oracle database sqlplus. Forgive me as I am a little wet behind the ears.

My plan is to assign to variables to the WHERE clause of the SELECT. One being the sysdate and the other being the target (number of days back) and using these date variables to set the date range in the SELECT query itself.

Right now,

I have the SELECT in a sql script which will spool the results into a csv file for the daily tasks (-1). However, the issue is, I am supposed to be doing the reporting for all three reports in a single script hence I don't think this route is going to work. My initial plan was to just call and exec this sql script to create the csv file then mv this file to the correct directory (as there are 3 directories daily/weekly/semiannually) by doing an
if/fi date comparison in the script.

**sqlScript.sql**

SELECT
...
FROM
...
WHERE
...
And trunc(statusTimeStamp)>=trunc(sysdate-1); <--- This is daily report

**script.sh**

## !/bin/bash

...
sqlplus kick off sqlScript.sql
...
write to logs

This is the summary of how I have my sh script and sql file setup.

Comment: show us what you've done

Comment: I'll edit, give me a sec.